# is it proper to use float64 data type with scikit-learn ML algorithms?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, decision-tree

I am trying to execute Decision Tree and SVM for a dataset given [here](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/spambase/spambase.data) using scikit-learn. My purpose is to compare these two algorithms so that I am using KFold cross-validation method for both algorithms and show the difference. But the dataset I am using, consist real number like 0.00057. I get accuracy that I can say there is no overfitting, but I am not sure if real numbers effect the results.

Is it a problem to give scikit-learn built-in classification functions real numbers ? If it is , what should I do get better results ?

PS: when I check the type of a single data in python I see it is float64.

Comment: What do you mean by real numbers? A float64 is a much higher precision than 0.00057, when you get the results you're either asking for a classification to a predicted class or some other evaluation such as probability likelihood or confidence, all of which will be calculated in float64

Comment: I mean high precision numbers by real numbers. When I load dataset into a 2D array, python sets array's type to float64. I wonder if it is better or not to use another data type while executing classification fit or predict functions.

Comment: Your data will be converted to the compatible dtypes that sklearn supports so unless your data is of higher precision than float64 it shouldn't be a problem

Comment: So there is no worry about datatypes when executing algorithms. Thanks!

Comment: I'd worry about range of your numbers. Usually, it's helpful to [standardize](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_score) your data, that is, make it have zero mean and unit variation.

Answer (score 2):

DecisionTreeClassifier and SVC internally use float32 to represent the features. They will convert any input data into this format. For machine learning tasks, that is usually more than enough precision.